# google-cloud dependencies getting overriden in python app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using GAE standard and as per google documentation, we are expected to vendor dependencies in some folder using `pip install requirement-name -t lib/`.

We want to use both `BigQuery` & `pub-sub` in the same GAE project which is I think not a very rare combination.

Now the **issue** is at a time we are able to install only one of the client libraries as both share `google>cloud` namespace whichever is installed later will override earlier dependency.

***Screenshots:-***

1) ***When only BigQuery client library is installed***:-

[image: only GBQ dependency screenshot]

2) **After installing `pip install -t lib/ google-cloud-pubsub`**

[image: after installing pubsub]

What can be the issue and solution for the same?

**UPDATE**:-

Further tried installing these two dependencies in the virtual environment without vendoring in `lib/` folder, there both dependencies are getting installed without overwriting each other. So looked like the issue is with vendoring in folder.

*Screenshot for the same without vendoring dependencies.*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding both libraries to a `requirements.txt` file and then run `pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes @Mangu tried it, in that case later dependency is overwriting the first dependency and at the end having only later dependency in `lib/` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install all the dependencies in a single command:

```
$ pip install -t lib/ google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-pubsub
```

This will install both packages along side each other:

```
$ ls lib/google/cloud
__pycache__  _testing.py  environment_vars.py  obsolete.py   pubsub_v1
_helpers.py  bigquery     exceptions.py        operation.py
_http.py     client.py    iam.py               pubsub.py
```

Installing the dependencies from a requirements file should have the same effect:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-pubsub
$ pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt
```

Make sure to start with an empty `lib/` folder, and with the latest version of `pip`:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: Thanks @Dustin, worked after deleting `lib/` folder, very weird!!! aware of any reason why it work only after deleting `lib` folder and then installing dependency?

Comment: Yes, because installing two dependencies in separate commands will "mark" both as installed, but the second one will overwrite the `lib/google/cloud` directory created by the first one. If you don't start with an empty `lib` directory, `pip` will think both have already been installed, and it will do nothing.